# How to build a responsive padding for list menus using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I created a menu which looks like this centered withing a div container:

```
|                                                   |
|       +--------+--------+--------+--------+       |
|       |  home  | teams  |  games |  about |       |
|       +--------+--------+--------+--------+       |
```

SC:

```
.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item > a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: 0.10s;
  transition: 0.10s;

  color: #fff;
  background-color: #757575;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* padding-left: ;  i want this to be responsive
  padding-right: ; */
}
```

What i really wanted to create though is a responsive menu which fills the white bezels on each sides.

```
|                                                   |
|+------------+------------+------------+----------+|
||    home    |   teams    |  games     |   about  ||
|+------------+------------+------------+----------+|
```

and changes the padding size when browser resizes:

```
|                                           |
|+----------+----------+----------+--------+|
||    home  |   teams  |  games   | about  ||
|+----------+----------+----------+--------+|
```

I tried adjusting the padding based on media sizes but i end up having a static look, as its only adjusting on several screen sizes and not dynamically.

Comment: If you want to make the padding, margin styling responsive always make it in percentage.

Comment: I thought the trick to responsive-ness was to always use relative units (like `em`). Are percentages more-responsive than other context-relative units?

Comment: i dont know. using % on padding does not work for me.

Comment: @Anthony.. You should use Bootstrap to make the menu responsive... without specifiying any size (percentage), using grid system...

Comment: @jitendrajoshi - Thanks for the tip, but I try to avoid using anything, since I am not a UI designer. I also try to avoid any specific libraries that might be obsolete in a year or make the underlying document polluted. But I think you really meant to direct your suggestion to the OP, who I am not.

Comment: @Anthony... oopss... by mistake..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect scenario where you can use a `flexbox`:

1. First reset the list styles:

   ```
   .main-navigation ul{
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Now declare it as a `flexbox` and align them with `space-around` like this:

   ```
   .main-navigation ul{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Now add `flex: 1` to each `li` to let it occupy all the available whitespace, and `text-align: center` to center the anchor tag inside the li:

   ```
   .main-navigation > ul > li {
     flex: 1;
    }
   ```
4. To finish things up, added some borders and styles for illustration.

```css
.main-navigation ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-navigation > ul > li {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #757575;
 
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item > a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: 0.10s;
  transition: 0.10s;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>teams</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>games</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I guess you can take it forward from here. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways (use flexbox, a `<table>`, or `display: table-cell;`) but the simplest might just be to set `width: 25%;` on your `<li>` tags there. Try:

```
.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item a {
    width: 100%;  /* or possibly just "display: block;" %/
}
```

Comment: its not filling the space on the div. its still centered. with width: 25%; its reduce to 25%

Comment: You might need to set the `width` and `display: inline-block` on the `<li>` actually. Just updated my answer, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested other forms of variable measurements besides rem? Example:

```
ul{
  background: #ccc;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  list-style:none;
}

li{
  align-items: center;
  background:#fff;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding:3em;
  margin:3em;
}

<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li> 
</ul>
```

or

```
ul{
  background: #ccc;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  list-style:none;
}

li{
  align-items: center;
  background:#fff;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding:4%;
  margin:4%;
}

<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li> 
</ul>
```

or media queries?

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 760px) {
li {
padding: this is for css on screens smaller than 760px;
}
.class { 
margin-top: don't forget to close media queries bracket though;
     } 
}
```